# Can't receive POST data through AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So what I'm trying to do, is send some jQuery variables to my PHP script using Ajax post. However, for some reason, I cannot set the PHP variables to contain the values of the jQuery variables.

I have tried multiple types of Ajax data, like forms (new FormData();) and arrays.

script.js

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'file.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    'document_id': document_id,
    'section_id': section_id,
    'active_state': active_state
  },
  beforeSend: function () {
    console.log('the data is: ' + document_id + section_id + active_state + '...');
  },
  success: function (response) {
    console.log(response + ' is locked!');
  },
  fail: function (error) {
    console.log(error + ' could not be locked');

});
```

file.php

```
print_r($_POST);
```

However, in the success function of the Ajax request, I DO receive an array back with the proper variables. When I check the output of the PHP file, it just returns a blank array.

This is what I eventually need to do:

```
if(isset($_POST['document_id'])){

    $document_id = $_POST['document_id'];
    $section_id = $_POST['section_id'];
    $active_state = $_POST['active_state'];

    // echo back the data to the success function
    // proceed with insert into database
} else {

  echo 'the data has not been set';    

}
```

Any insights on what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: before ajax `alert('document_id');`

Comment: @kerbholz I fire the ajax request first, then I enter mydomain.com/file.php. This returns a blank array

Comment: If you "just" enter `mydomain.com/file.php` in your browser the method will be `GET`, not `POST`, so `print_r($_POST);` will return empty. Use your browsers development tools to see the response you get via AJAX.

Comment: how do you init the ajax req? Also try returning (well echoing) a print_r of $_POST to see if anything passes at all

Comment: The "if" section of your php file should work, however you are not echoing back something to be logged in the success function of your ajax request.

Comment: @treyBaken I have tried returning, but like I said, file.php just returns an empty array

Comment: @Wizard I am aware of this, I have removed that piece of code, as that is not the problem here. The code reverts to the else statement.

Comment: So, are you getting "the data has not been set is locked!" in your browser console log?

Comment: Add `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: Can you confirm that if you do `die('test')` just before your `print_r($_POST);` in your php file you will see `test` it in the JavaScript success function  ?

Comment: Hey, are you getting any error in your browser console?

Comment: @Wizard No. The if statement is what I eventually want to do. As of now, I simply have  `print_r($_POST);`. In the console log I get the back the array containing all the proper values is locked!

Comment: @Accountantم confirmed. I see `test` in the success function

Comment: @pu4cu, so what is the problem? your ajax request works. The php file gets the proper values, so use them in your database call.

Comment: @Wizard the problem is that I need to put the proper values into variables. But if I try to do that, I get an error like `undefined index: document_id`. The POST data has not been set.

Comment: @pu4cu, but when is that happening? When YOU call manually 'file.php' in your browser?

Comment: Are you sure the request has left the browser with the proper data and parameters names ? check in your browser network monitor.

Comment: @pu4cu *" yes, exactly"*... Then, did you read kerbholz comment that has the most up-votes ? if you type `domain/file.php` in the browser address bar this is GET request not POST.

Comment: @pu4cu, what you're doing makes no sense. Your php file works fine. When jquery makes an ajax request to your script, it calls file.php and provides it with the POST data you have set up. When it finishes, it echoes back whatever you want and all its php variables are gone. When you call it manually, you provide it with no POST data, that's why you see the error. Put the database code in your php script and it will work with your jquery code.

Comment: @kerbholz ok, I checked inside the development tools to see what kind of response I'm getting back, and it seems you were right. Inside the development tools I do get all the proper values back. However, I need to assign a variable to them in PHP and when I do that, I get `undefined index: variable name`.

Comment: This code `if(isset($_POST['document_id'])){ $document_id = $_POST['document_id'];` can never produce `undefined index: document_id`

Comment: which version of jquery you are using ? if you are using jQuery version > 1.9.0 use method instead of type.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use this to get the response from ajax request

```
<?php

   extract($_POST);

   print_r($_POST);
 ?>
```

Comment: this isn't needed^^

Comment: I have tried this and I still get back a blank array.

Comment: After sending ajax request in success call back u can console.log(data) then you will get the response